# VBA - excel não reconhece vírgula de dados externos

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Bom dia a todos!

Estou tentando integrar o excel a outro software (o EES - Engineering Equation Solver) através de um código em vba.

Meu programa copia determinadas colunas de uma tabela, transfere para o outro programa, realiza os cálculos, copia os resultados e cola nas colunas correspondentes da minha tabela no excel. O próprio site de ajuda do EES disponibiliza um programa de exemplo para operação, que estou usando como base.

O problema é que o meu programa retorna valores decimais e o excel não está reconhecendo a vírgula dos dados colados! O estranho é que dados decimais copiados do excel para o EES são interpretados corretamente e se eu copio e colo os dados do EES manualmente na planilha o número vem com a vírgula corretamente!

Meu excel já está ajustado para reconhecer vírgula como separador decimal, igual ao EES. O código segue abaixo:

```
Private Sub cmdDDE_Click()
Dim ChNumber As Integer
Dim myShell As String

ChNumber = -1
myShell = frmEESDDE.txtApp.Text

On Error Resume Next

'Copy selected rows into clipboard
Range("B2:G1401").Select
Selection.Copy

Shell_R = Shell(myShell, 1)

If Shell_R <> "" Then
    'Initiate DDE
    ChNumber = Application.DDEInitiate(app:="ees", topic:="")

    If ChNumber <> -1 Then
        'Open EES
        Application.DDEExecute ChannelNumber, "[Open C:\EES\Tablesolve.ees]"
        'Paste data
        Application.DDEExecute ChannelNumber, "[Paste Parametric 'Table 1' R1 C1]"
        'Solve parametrictable
        Application.DDEExecute ChannelNumber, "[SOLVETABLE 'TABLE 1' Rows=1..1400]"
        'Copy results
        Application.DDEExecute ChannelNumber, "[COPY ParametricTable 'Table 1' R1 C7:R1400 C14]"
        'Choose separators
        Application.DecimalSeparator = ","
        Application.ThousandsSeparator = "."
        Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
        'Paste results from EES into EXCEL
        Application.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H2:O1440")
        Application.UseSystemSeparators = True
        'Quit EES and Terminate DDE
        DDEExecute ChNumber, "QUIT"
        Application.DDETerminate ChNumber
    Else
        MsgBox "Unable to initiate connection to EES", vbExclamation, "EES DDE"
    End If

    frmEESDDE.Hide

Else
        MsgBox "The application, " & myShell & ", was not found", vbExclamation, "EES DDE"
End If
```

End Sub

PS = Notem que eu já tentei usar o comando  **Application.DecimalSeparator = ","**  mas não deu certo. Meu resultado de, por exemplo, "15,47" aparece no excel como "1,55E+12" ou como "1547421377050".

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda!

Comment: como está o separador decimal do seu Windows? Pergunto isso, pois você diz para usar o separador decimal do sistema operacional (Application.UseSystemSeparators = True). Se você quiser usar o separador decimal setado por você, então você deve deixar essa propriedade como false, ou seja, Application.UseSystemSeparators = False. Aliás, note que você seta ele como false e logo abaixo como true.

Comment: Sim, o Windows está na configuração "português brasil" cujo default é a vírgula como separador decimal. O excel e o EES seguem automaticamente essas definições e também já conferi que os dois estão ajustados para reconhecer a vírgula como separador decimal. No caso da parte do código que define os separadores, segui a sugestão desse link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28105731/pasting-decimal-numbers-in-excel-comma-and-point-decimal-separator
Nele, usa-se Application.UseSystemSeparators = False antes e depois de colar volta ao normal fazendo Application.UseSystemSeparators = True.

Comment: eu não encontrei o método Application.Paste no meu Excel (versao 2010). Tente, por favor, fazer o seguinte: Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H2").PasteSpecial ao invés de fazer Application.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H2:O1440"). Além disso, abra o notepad e tente Colar pra ver como o dado está vindo depois da execução dessa linha (Application.DDEExecute ChannelNumber, "[COPY ParametricTable 'Table 1' R1 C7:R1400 C14]").

Comment: Testei trocar o comando e por **Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H2").PasteSpecial** como vc sugeriu mas  ai o código cola novamente as variáveis de entrada ao invés de colar os resultados. O mesmo ocorre no notepad. Para colar no notepad usei os comandos: 
`Shell "notepad.exe", vbNormalFocus
SendKeys "^V"`

PS= não tenho mt experiência com VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desconheço essa aplicação (ESS), por isso fica difícil de te ajudar de uma maneira mais específica.

Porém, exsite algo genérico que você pode fazer e que muito provavelmente resolverá o seu problema, você incluirá isso no seu VBA de tal maneira que o processo fique automático.

Como você disso, o que está ocorrendo é o que o Excel está esperando "," como separador decimal, mas está sendo colado ".". Os 5 passos abaixo são resumidos da seguinte maneira:

- Mudar o tipo de todas as células que receberão número para texto
- Colar os dados provenientes do EES
- Substituir, para cada célula, "." por ","
- Mudar o tipo de todas as células para General
- Forçar que cada célula seja reconhecida como Double

Veja os passos detalhados abaixo:

1. Declare o intervalo a ser utilizado como um range, para evitar repetir código:

   Dim intervalo as Range

   Set intervalo = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H2:O1440")
2. **Antes** do passo de Colar os dados no Excel, altere todas as células que receberão números para o tipo Texto. Isso pode ser feito com a seguinte instrução:

   intervalo.NumberFormat = "@"
3. Feito o passo acima, você deverá executar a instrução que cola os dados no Excel e, logo depois, executar o trecho de código abaixo. Este trecho substitui, para cada célula do intervalo, o caracter "." pelo caracter ",".

   Dim Cell as Range

   For Each Cell In intervalo
      Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, ",", ".")
   Next
4. Agora retorne todas as células do intervalo para o formato geral:

   intervalo.NumberFormat = "General"
5. Como último passo, execute o trecho de código abaixo, que converterá o valor de cada célula em um Double. Isso deve ser feito pois o Excel reconhecerá cada valor como texto e você não conseguirá aplicar contas e fórmulas nos mesmos.

   Dim Cell as Range

   For Each Cell In intervalo
      Cell.Value = CDbl(Cell.Value)
   Next

**Alguns Comentários**

O passo 3 poderia ser feito utilizando Replace do próprio Range. Isso eliminaria a necessidade de do loop. Porém, embore funcione quando você grava uma macro, não funciona quando você executa a macro. Pessoas já reportaram isso (ver: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437372/selection-replace-doesnt-replace-commas-with-a-dot)

Dependendo do número de células que devem ser percorridas pelos dois laço for, a solução pode ficar lenta.

Tanto o passo 3 quanto o passo 5, são realizados por algum tipo de bug do Excel e esses são os passos mais lentos, pois necessitam do loop.

Comment: Cantoni, muito obrigada!!! Esse conjunto de passos resolveu o problema sem deixar o programa muito lento. A única modificação que tive que fazer para funcionar foi pular o passo número 3, pois os números já estavam com o separador "," no programa de origem. No mais, segui suas recomendações e deu certo.

Comment: Só mais uma observação: os resultados estavam sendo colados com muitas casas decimais após a vírgula, então adicionei mais uma linha de código no loop do passo 5: `Cell.Value = FormatNumber(CDbl(Cell.Value), 2)` antes de `Cell.Value = CDbl(Cell.Value)` para colar resultados apenas com duas casas decimais.